# How to delete specific rows from multiple csv files in powershell?

Tags: powershell, rows

Hello I'm looking for a effective way to delete second and last row from multiple csv files? I have around 5000 files in a directory.
The code below will delete first line. If I use parameter -skip 2. It will skip first 2 rows, but I need to keep first row and delete second row and last row. I'm also not sure if get-content set-content is proper way to go for such a big number of files.

```
foreach ($file in gci *.csv ){
(gc $file) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | set-content $file
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a word on the performance. I used @TheMadTechnician method of getting the content and compared 3 different methods of writing the output. I used 100 1MB input files for each test. Below are the results:

Using Out-File to overwrite the contents took 1 minute 32 seconds.

```
dir *.txt | %{
    $content = gc $_.FullName
    $content | select -First 1 | Out-File $_.FullName -Force
    $content[2..($content.count -2)]|Out-File $_.FullName -Append
}
```

Using Set-Content to overwrite the contents took 37 seconds.

```
dir *.txt | %{
    $content = gc $_.FullName
    $output = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $output += $content[2..($content.count -2)]
    $output | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force
}
```

Using a StreamWriter to overwrite the contents took 31 seconds.

```
dir *.txt | %{     
    $content = gc $_.FullName
    $output = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $output += $content[2..($content.count -2)]
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($_.FullName,$false)
    $output | %{$sw.WriteLine($_)}
    $sw.close()
}
```

You might want to look into these different approaches for your particular situation, but I have always found that Out-File is far slower than Set-Content or a StreamWriter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Stephen. The last code is really really  fast. Looks like you are really good in PS. Could you please help with one more problem? Can a similar code by used to change date format (it is stored in first column of those files) from m/d/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy or do i need to post another question?

Comment: I would post another question as its a different issue. Try looking at get-date, import-csv, export-csv, and the custom datetime format providers and see if you can figure it out first.

Comment: Good to know about Out-File being so slow. I had no idea, but will be sure to take this into consideration in the future! Excellent answer

Comment: Hello Stephen.I just posted that question I mentioned above.It would be great if you cold review my code and suggest how to improve it. Thank you. John   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399452/change-date-format-in-multiple-text-files-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best approach but you could use `-Index` and calculate the rows you want.

```
foreach ($file in gci *.csv ){
    $data = gc $file
    $data | Select-Object -Index (,0 + (2..($data.Count - 2))) | set-content $file
}
```

Indexing, for arrays, starts at 0 so we take that one and skip record 1. After we just take the rest minus the last. `-Index` takes and integer array so we create a single element array of value 0 and append the indexes from 2 until then end of the file minus the last ( which is where `-2` comes from since `.Count` starts at 1) .

Comment: He wants the first line, but not the second line or last line. He wants to eliminate records 1 and -1

Comment: I'm getting error here. "Cannot convert value "Select" to type "System.int32". "Input string was not in correct format"

Comment: Yeah... i made another error on that one by mixing my test code with yours.. If you want to have a look again... _maybe_ it performs better

Comment: Thank you very much Your code is about 45% faster than TheMadTechnician's That really saves a lot of time when handling with a large number of files.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, I'd just pipe through a Where clause in your code to skip item 1 and item -1 in each file. Like this:

```
(gci *.csv )|ForEach{
    $file = $_
    $contents = gc $file
    $contents | Where{$_ -ne $contents[1] -and $_ -ne $contents[-1]} | out-file $file.fullname -force
}
```

I did the ForEach inline to make sure that the GCI finishes and isn't holding anything open when you try to do the Out-File

**Edit:** I just realized that my code has a potential flaw in that if you have duplicate lines to either line 2 or the last line those lines would be eliminated as well. I wrote this assuming you had something like the following that you wanted to clean up:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
---- ---- ---- ----
Data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data
Log Created: 02/04/2015
```

Where you wanted to remove the --- line and the log created note at the end.

**Edit2:** A better solution would probably be to get the content of the file, outputting the first line, and then outputting lines 3 through the end (minus 1 line) and appending it to the same file. Something like:

```
(gci *.csv )|ForEach{
    $Path = $_.FullName
    $content = gc $Path
    $content|select -first 1|Out-File $Path -force
    $content[2..($content.count-2)]|Out-File $Path -Append
}
```

Comment: Similar error is here. "Cannot bind argument to parameter "Path" because it is null" .  $contents = gc $file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to re-assisgn $file after I changed the ForEach method. I've updated it now, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you it works. Only problem is that it is quite slow. For 5000 files it took more  than 7 minutes to run.On google I've found something about    IO.StreamReader to read a large number of files, but I'm not sure It it can by used in my case.